# Select last message from all conversations (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, message

I need to select all the last messages for each conversation for user with given id.
In case of last message was send to given id, it have to be last message from sender.

Here is the test case without creationDate using messageID:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
| messageID | fromUserID | toUserID | text |
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
| 1         | 1          | 2        | 'aa' |
| 2         | 1          | 3        | 'ab' |
| 3         | 2          | 1        | 'ac' |
| 4         | 2          | 1        | 'ad' |
| 5         | 3          | 2        | 'ae' |
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
```

The result for userID=1 have to be messages with text 'ab' and 'ad'.

For now I have this query with all of the last messages of every user to each other, but does not remove, according to my test case, message with id=1 (have to be only with id=2 and id=4).

```
SELECT
    UM.messageID,
    UM.fromUserID, UM.toUserID,
    UM.text, UM.flags, UM.creationDate
FROM UserMessage AS UM
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(messageID) AS maxMessageID
        FROM UserMessage
        GROUP BY fromUserID, toUserID
    ) IUM
    ON UM.messageID = IUM.maxMessageID
WHERE UM.fromUserID = 1 OR UM.toUserID = 1
ORDER BY UM.messageID DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: In your query (1,2) differs from (2,1). Use `GROUP BY LEAST(fromUserID, toUserID) , GREATEST(fromUserID, toUserID)` in your subquery. PS. And `WHERE 1 IN (UM.fromUserID, UM.toUserID)` in main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method is

```
select um.*
from usermessage um
where um.messageid = (select min(um2.messageid)
                      from usermessage um2
                      where (um2.fromuserid, touserid) in ( (um.fromuserid, um.touserid), (um.touserid, um.fromuserid) )
                     );
```

Or, in MySQL 8+:

```
select um.*
from (select um.*,
             row_number() over (partition by least(um.fromuserid, um.touserid), greatest(um.fromuserid, um.touserid) order by um.messageid desc) as seqnum
      from usermessage um
     ) um
where seqnum = 1;
```